# My get element by ID is not working

Tags: javascript, html

There is something wrong with this code.

HTML

```
<p id = "Krishna"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("Krishna").innerHTML = "Hello"
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: When do you execute that js? Are you doing it before the DOM is ready?

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/exsspjx8/  Do you have any code that actually demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling your script in the code above. I use the same code with a function:

```
<script>
function fun(){ 
 document.getElementById("Krishna").innerHTML = "Hello";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload='fun()'>
<p id = "Krishna"></p>

</body>
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: thanks for the help, i haven't tried it yet but it looks like a solution